# Pandas groupby sorting

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, group-by

I am trying to analyze my Netflix data with pandas. I want to summarize the time each user spent watching a specific title and print the highest value for each Profile.

```
df_clean.sample(4)
```

| Profile Name | Duration | time_clean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 0 days 00:20:00 | Harry Potter |
| AAA | 0 days 00:41:50 | The Sinner |
| BBB | 0 days 00:00:15 | Avatar |
| AAA | 0 days 00:15:00 | Harry Potter |

I want to see only the first row for each Profile

I tried to use:

```
df_clean.groupby(['Profile Name','title_clean'])['Duration'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).nlargest(1)
```

But it's returning me only the biggest result for 1 Profile

| Profile Name | title_clean |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | Harry Potter | 0 days 00:35:00 |

Comment: Not sure `sum()` would cut it in the way you call sum. Already, sum is 'summing' up and not 'highest'/'max'. For groupby, have you try `agg`, `transform`.

Answer (score 2):

You can chain another `groupby(level = 0)` and `head(1)` to get the result you're looking for.

```
df_clean.groupby(['Profile Name', 'title_clean'])['Duration'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).groupby(level = 0).head(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
(df_clean.groupby(['Profile Name','title_clean'])['Duration'].sum()
 .loc[lambda g: g.groupby('Profile Name').idxmax()]
 .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  Profile Name title_clean        Duration
0          AAA  The Sinner 0 days 00:41:50
1          BBB      Avatar 0 days 00:00:15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    dd1=dd.groupby("title_clean")['Duration'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(1)
    return dd1.rename("Duration")
df1.groupby('Profile Name').apply(function1)
```

out：

```
Profile Name  title_clean
AAA           The Sinner     0 days 00:41:50
BBB           Avatar         0 days 00:00:15
```